# Flutter crash when theres no internet

Tags: api, http, flutter, connectivity

my app (literally took it from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)) crashes whenever i disable internet connection, works like a charm with internet. how can i still able to access the page, displaying the last accessed result without getting stuck? i have all the internet permission included in manifest.

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

this is the code

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response, then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response, then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({this.userId, this.id, this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.title);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [connectivity library](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) to listen for wifi status

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();

  subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    // Got a new connectivity status!
  })
}

// Be sure to cancel subscription after you are done
@override
dispose() {
  super.dispose();

  subscription.cancel();
}
```

Comment: the app still crashed

Answer (score 0):

Use the Connectivity library to check network status, before making any HTTP requests.

Comment: the app crashes and stuck (have to force close) and i got this crash message: 'Exception has occurred.
SocketException (SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7))',  it works fine when theres internet connection

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, with no additional packages, is to put the code that connects to the internet in try/catch block. You must return a default object of Album, an empty list `[]` in case there is a list of Albums, in the catch block or `throw` an exception.

In your case, the code can be like this:

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
      try{
        final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the server did return a 200 OK response, then parse the JSON.
          return Album.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        } else {
          // If the server did not return a 200 OK response, then throw an exception.
          throw Exception('Failed to load album');
        }
      } catch(_){
        print("No Internet Connection");
        return Album(userId=-1, id=-1, title=''});
    }
```

You can show a message to the user indicating the problem. You can do it like this:

```
showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                      title: Text('No Internet Connection',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      content: Text('No Internet Connection. Please connect to the internet and try again'),
                    ),
                barrierDismissible: true);
```